# How to show buffers without full path?

Tags: vim, buffer

When I execute `:ls` in vim, I see all buffers with full path, except for the file in the active buffer. With long paths and a not so large editor window, the buffer list get wrapped. In this way, searching for a buffer takes a while, especially when you have a lot of buffers open. Is there a possibility to show all buffers without full path?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the format of `:ls`. It shows paths relative to your current working directory (`:pwd`).

You can change the current working directory either via `:cd` or `:lcd`.

Also you might find the option `:help 'autochdir'` interesting, too.

EDIT:

I should clarify on *relative* here:

Files within the current working directory are shown relative and files outside of it are shown absolute. Absolute paths can be shortened, e.g. by using `~` instead of `/home/user` on Unix systems.